# Django Homepage 400 when debug=False

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-400

So my app works fine in the development server when Debug=True, however, when I switch it to False, my homepage is giving me back a 400 back. I have some endpoints which return json and they work fine regardless of the debug value.

I'm using Django 1.10.2

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.contrib import admin
from fim_table import views


urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', views.create_home),
    url(r'^data/', views.data),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from lockdown.decorators import lockdown
from .models import Fim, FimDeleted
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
import json


@csrf_protect
def create_home(request):
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'csrf': csrf})


# returns all of the data, unfiltered/response is json
@csrf_protect
def data(request):
    # show distinct names only
    fims = Fim.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('crib_name')).order_by('name_lower').distinct('name_lower')
    # fims need to be not a queryset but an array of dicts to be json
    dictionaries = [ idToString(name.as_dict()) for name in fims ]
    mydata = {"aaData": dictionaries}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(mydata), content_type='application/json')
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

**update**
I implemented some logging, and got:

The joined path (/DataTables/datatables.min.css) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/me/development/my_project/myapp/staticfiles).

I'm thinking this is a whitenoise issue, even though I set up my settings.py exactly like it is in their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

Comment: Nothing in the logs?

Comment: `[21/Nov/2016 21:46:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27` is it

Comment: That is error 500, not error 400. Either way, you should enable more logging so you get the actual exception.

Comment: Try looking in the web server error log, not the access log.

Comment: I changed something to get the `500` error. Now the logs are correctly showing my `400` error and I've updated my question with some logging info

Answer (score 0):

Try adding hostnames in the allowed hosts section.

```
For Ex: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'localhost_projectname', 'server_hostname']
```

You can find more details about how to add 404 and 500 pages in your site in the given blog post,

https://micropyramid.com/blog/handling-custom-error-pages-in-django/